# SQL Query to get the Users that have friends within the top Nth percentile

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am interested in getting the users who are in the top 10 percentile of friends in a social network database.

The code snippet below gets all users who have the maximum number of friends.

```
SELECT
    h.name,
    h.grade
FROM
    highschooler h,
    friend f
where
    h.id = f.id1
group by
    f.id1
having
    count(f.id2) <= (
        select
            max(r.c)
        from
        (
            select
                count(id2) as c
            from
                friend
            group by
                id1
        ) as r)
```

My database looks something like this:

```
Highschooler ( ID, name, grade )
```

> There is a high school student with unique ID and a given first name in a certain grade.

```
Friend ( ID1, ID2 )
```

> The student with ID1 is friends with the student with ID2. Friendship is mutual, so if (123, 456) is in the Friend table, so is (456, 123).

I'm wondering whether there is a percentile function that could be used instead of the `MAX` function. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get the users that have friends within the top 10th percentile?

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  The answer could easily depend.

Comment: I added it, I believe. Do you need more info on the database itself?

Comment: Are you using `sql server`, `mysql`, `oracle` or some other database?

Comment: Oh, I'm using RedShift

Comment: What do you mean by "top percentile of friends"?

Comment: Their friend count is within the top Nth percentile.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. Let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PERCENTILE_DISC` which can solve your usecase. You can read more about [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_PERCENTILE_DISC_WF.html)

simple example :

```
select sellerid, qty, percentile_cont(0.9) 
within group (order by qty)  -- sort criteria on the field 
over(partition by sellerid) as median from winsales -- partition;
```